# Recalculate the derivative of second order using some substitutions.

Tags: calculus, derivatives, substitution

This question only regards to elementary manipulations with variables. I don't look into any technical details.

Consider two functions $F,f$ and two variables $s,x$. And a real number $E$. We have
$$F(s) = Ef(x)$$
and
$$s = Ee^x$$

I would like to calculate the $$\frac{d^2 F}{d s^2}$$ in terms of $f,x$
I know this may be simple, but only what i have got is the following ridiculous result:
$$s^2 = E^2e^{2x}$$
$\frac{ds^2}{dx} = 2 E e^{2x}$, $\frac{dx}{dx^2}=\frac{1}{2 x}$. So we may multiply both sides to get:
$$\frac{ds^2}{dx}\cdot \frac{dx}{dx^2} = \frac{ds^2}{dx^2} = \frac{E^2e^{2x}}{2 x}$$.

So we may put that altogether:
$$\frac{d^F}{ds^2}=\frac{E d^2 f}{\frac{E^2 e^{2x}dx^2}{2x}}=\frac{2x d^2 f}{E e^{2x}dx^2}$$
Which it seems strange to me.

I hope you will help me.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1):

I would simply use the chain rule as
$$\frac{dF}{ds}=Ef’(x)x_s$$  $$\frac{d^{2}F}{ds^2}=Ef’’(x){x_s}^2+Ef’(x)x_{ss}$$
and then use the fact $x_s s_x = 1$

For notation I am writing $x_s$ as the derivative of $x$ with respect to $s$.